# Visual Studio 2017 fails to recognize a namespace

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, user-controls

I'm developing an app in UWP, C#/XAML.

I have a bunch of UserControl's, recently moved the .xaml and .xaml.cs files to a dedicated folder called VisualControls, and added the .VisualControls to the namespaces of all classes

Seems like a bug in VS2017, the IDE fails to find the control classes in the namespace.

[image: VS does not find the class of user control, if I remove the xmlns reference, the IDE suggests the very same xmlns reference, and the error persist]

VS does not find the class of user control, if I remove the xmlns:VisualControls reference in the file Capacitor.xaml (or other users of the GroupBox control), the IDE suggests the very same xmlns reference, and the error persist

below the CS of GroupBox User Control
[image: CS file of UserControl]

below the XAML of GroupBox User Control
[image: XAML file of UserControl]

I'm stuck here.. :( , what can I do?

Comment: close all visual studio and try opening again

Comment: tried that already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a common bug but very simple to solve, right click your solution and clean solution twice, after that just rebuild your solution and problem will go away.

Comment: done right as you said, cleaned twice, the rebuild solution/project., but didn't work, problem persists :(

Comment: it is hard to believe, but seems the problem is caused by Intellisense, I closed all documents, (no xaml left open), restart VS2017, and rebuild. builds fine, open xaml again, and there is no error. who knows..

Comment: yes that is actually strange and yeah that is also one of the solutions, but mostly it is solved by cleaning, VS can be sometimes unreasonable :P

Comment: but its good that you know all the possible reasons of the problem now :)